# Why does CreateWindowEx WS_POPUP make a border?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am trying to find out why my application has a small, few pixel, border.

My understanding is that `WS_POPUP` should take care of the problem;

```
DWORD wndExStyle = WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
DWORD wndStyle =  WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU;
g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(wndExStyle, wcl.lpszClassName, L"junk",
wndStyle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, wcl.hInstance, 0);
//Somewhere later
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
wglCreateContextAttribsARB(g_hDC, 0, attribList);
//Finally
ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);
```

edit 1:
removed WS_BORDER

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That border is caused by the use of [`WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx#WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW). The fact that `WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is defined as `WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` makes it very clear what is going on.

Remove that extended style and the border goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Including WS_BORDER in the style causes a thin border to be added to the window.  Remove it from the style.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, or make a difference.